# How can I create Eclipse-style folders from the Terminal?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to create Eclipse-style folders (Project Folder, Package and so on) via the Terminal?

I once renamed an Eclipse package like this: `mv oldname newname`, and I noticed that after doing so, Eclipse no longer considered the folder a Package.

This possibly means that it is a matter of metadata, but I have so far been unsuccessful in locating the files containing the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not provide anything to do this and it is not really possible manually.

For a project some information is stored in the `.project` file in the project folder. Depending on the type of project there may also be a `.classpath` file and there will also be data stored in the `.metadata` folder in the workspace and also in a `.settings` folder in the project.

All the file and folder names starting with `.` are considered to be hidden on Linux, Unix and Mac systems and are not shown by default. Use the `-a` flag of `ls` to see them.